# Splitters in scikit learn decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree

I'm trying to understand the implementation of splitters of decision tree in scikit learn.But I have stuck the point where it start finding the best split.

Need help in understanding the algo that is going on in it.

Code that I need to understand in from line 352 (in this file [https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx )which basically the heart of decision tree built

Comment: im also interested in the same question. Will have a look at it as soon as I find the time. I'm no scikit developer thoug